# Dividend Coverage Ratio and Preferred Stock

Tags: investing, dividends, preferred-stocks, stock-dividend

I am looking at investing in a few companies which offer preferred stock. Do their dividend coverage ratios factor in the dividends being paid to preferred shareholders? If not, how can I find or determine an 'adjusted dividend coverage ratio' that includes preferred stock?
Thank you.

Comment: "Do their dividend coverage ratios factor in the dividends being paid to preferred shareholders?" — Where did you get the data for the dividend coverage ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Dividend Coverage Ratio is calculated as the total net income *minus any required preferred dividend*, divided by the amount of the dividend. It can also be calculated as EPS/DPS, where EPS is net income minus preferred dividends.

So, yes, they factor in the dividends being paid to preferred shareholders.